# Error: Expected identifier or '(' before 'int'

Tags: c, struct

I keep getting this error. Any clue what is wrong?

```
struct numFreq(int* num, int* frequency) {
    int num, frequency;
};
```

Comment: Is that a function definition or a structure definition?

Comment: @user3386109, Structure definition. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: That's not how you define a struct in c so I assume its a function...

Comment: No offence, but if you have to ask that, you really should re-read that chapter in your C book.

Comment: Answer below has it. Here is some additional help if you need it. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_structures.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing the syntax for functions with that of structs. Try this:

```
struct numFreq {
  int num, frequency;
};
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me.

Comment: @Team41 don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you out.